# Why is a two-qubit state described by a point in a 15-dimensional space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-computer, density-operator, quantum-states

While trying to understand the basics of how quantum computers work, I recently read this statement.

*"...consider that single-qubit states can be represented by a point inside a sphere in 3-dimensional space. Two-qubit states, in comparison, need to be represented as a point in 15-dimensional space..."*

**Can someone explain why a point in 15 dimensions (or 15 values) is required to describe the state of a two bit quantum computer.** (I already understand the concepts of entanglement, superposition etc.)

Answer (score 5):

The state of $n$ qubits is described by a $2^n \times 2^n$ [density matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix). A density matrix can contain complex values, but it is always [Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix) (equal to its own adjoint) and its [Trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) always equals 1.

*(Density matrices are flexible enough to describe both superpositions and classical uncertainty. If there is no uncertainty, i.e. you know the exact pure state, you can describe that pure state with just a $2^n$-dimensional vector instead of the quadratically larger density matrix.)*

---

Let's count the degrees of freedom of a $2^n \times 2^n$ density matrix.

We start with $2^n \cdot 2^n$ complex degrees of freedom, one for each coefficient in the matrix. We double that to get $2^{2n+1}$ real degrees of freedom. We drop back to $2^{2n}$ due to losing half of the degrees of freedom to the Hermitian-ness. Then we lose one more due to the unit-trace constraint. The final total is $2^{2n} - 1$.

When $n=2$, we find that $2^{2n}-1=2^4-1=16-1=15$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The linear Hilbert space $H$ of $n$ [qubits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit) has $2^n$ complex dimensions. The set of [density operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix) on $H$, which by definition are Hermitian (actually semipositive) and have trace $=1$ must then have real dimension $(2^n)^2-1$.

Answer (score -2):

The quoted statement is, strictly speaking, false.  But it's pretty clear what the author meant to say.

If we interpret "state" to mean "pure state" then the state space for a single cubit is the projectivization of a two-dimensional complex vector space. Therefore it has one complex dimension, which is to say two real dimensions.  The state space for a pair of qubits is the projectivization of a four-dimensional complex vector space (the tensor product of the two spaces corresponding to the original qubits).  Therefore it has three complex dimensions, which is to say six real dimensions.

If we interpret "state" to mean "mixed state" then the state space for a single qubit is the space of all probability distributions on the pure state space, i.e. the space of all probability distributions on the 2-sphere.  This is already infinite-dimensional.

But if the author said "state" when he meant "density operator", then the numbers match up, per Qmechanic's answer.

Comment: A mixed state of a qubit is *not* infinite-dimensional, and it is *not* the space of all probability distributions over pure state space.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch:  Your comment surprises me; I thought a mixed state was (by definition!) a probability distribution over pure states. I'm sure I've said this in print without raising any objections from otherwise-cranky referees.  On the other hand, I have no doubt that you are (far!) better educated than me about this, so I will do some Googling --- and will be grateful if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I would use "mixed state" as a synonym for "density operator".  There is no way of claiming that a mixed state is a *specific* mixture on physical grounds -- there is no way of experimentally distinguishing "different" mixtures described by the same density operator $\rho$.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch:  I've always used "mixed state" to mean a probability distribution, recognizing of course that these mixed states fall into equivalence classes parameterized by the corresponding density operators, and that two equivalent mixed states can't be experimentally distinguished.  Of course, as far as substance goes, you and I are choosing different language to describe exactly the same thing.  Some quick Googling suggests to me that my preferred language is more widely used than yours, but as I said before, I'm sure  you're a lot more familiar with this literature than I am.

Comment: My experience is that many people have misconceptions about mixtures of quantum mechanical states, so I wouldn't give too much on what you find on the internet.  Certainly, if you consider a "state" to describe what you know about a system, and what allows you to *predict* the outcome of future measurements (rather than tell you sth. about the past), then a state is just a density operator.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch:  This is surely not worth an extended discussion, but for the record I don't see where any misconceptions are involved --- just a choice of language.  I don't see anyone claiming that all mixed states (when defined as probability distributions over pure states) are experimentally distinguishable.

Comment: Wikipedia: *A mixed state cannot be described as a ket vector. Instead, it is described by its associated density matrix (or density operator), usually denoted ρ.*

Comment: @NorbertSchuch:  I wouldn't have considered Wikipedia an authoritative source.  But if that's your standard, then the **very same article you quote** says that   *A mixed quantum state is a statistical ensemble of pure states*, and when I follow the link to "statistical ensemble" I am told that *a statistical ensemble is a probability distribution for the state of the system.*

Comment: So following wikipedia, the number of parameters needed to describe a mixed state is different from the number of parameters needed to describe the description of a mixed state? :-o

Comment: @NorbertSchuch:  No, it seems to me that the natural interpretation is that the number of parameters needed to describe a mixed state is different from the number of parameters needed to describe an *equivalence class* of mixed states --- which is not an uncommon situation.  (Though, yes, this means that "it is described by its density matrix" is somewhat sloppy language --- better to say "it is described *up to equivalence* by its density matrix".)

Comment: I think we **strongly** disagree.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch:  I strongly disagree that we strongly disagree.  We are using different language to describe exactly the same thing.  That does not seem to me to count as a substantial disagreement.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch:  Some quotes --- Umesh Vazirani:  *In general, we can think of a mixed state as a collection of pure states, each with associated probability distribution*.  Richard Cleve:  *A probability distribution on pure states is called a mixed state*.  So if we do strongly disagree, then Vazirani and Cleve are on my side.  (I've also found several authors on your side.)   And with that, I will let this lie!

Comment: Correction to above:  "Each with associated probability distribution" in Vazirani quote should of course be "Each with associated probability".